# How do I connect a 62pin SNES connector to a breadboard?

Tags: connector, components, breadboard

I have a 62pin SNES connector.  It is too narrow to fit on the breadboard like I would an IC.  I thought about filing down two breadboards so there is a thinner "trench."

Is there any adapter I can use?  I know it is a proprietary part, but I thought it might be possible to fit somehow before I started filing down breadboards.

More generally, I think this could apply to anything.  What do you do with parts that won't fit the breadboard, non-standard?

Comment: Generally, you'd make a breakout board that you can fit into the breadboard!

Comment: That means I find a PCB that can fit the trench and my 62 pins, doesn't it?

Comment: You could cut down a standard veroboard or protoboard if it fits the 0.1" spacing, but if it doesn't, you'd probs have to get a PCB made somewhere.

Comment: mini (170 hole) breadboards don't have a bus, and you can often remove the bus on medium size (400 hole) ones. Without a bus, two breadboards side-by-side can be used without any modification.

Comment: @johnny well, he said "make", but yes.